# How can I install mods for Minecraft's vanilla server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen this question answered for bukkit but not vanilla minecraft server. I've been told that vanilla minecraft does not support mods but when I go to buildcraft's main site, (http://www.mod-buildcraft.com/installation/manual-server/), it is alluding to installing using the vanilla Minecraft server. Also, he states that the bukkit version of his mod is maintained by someone else (so his server mod should be for vanilla Minecraft, right?)

I've even seen a youtube video on how to install ModLoaderMP for vanilla Minecraft server, but when I follow those directions and run the server, I get an error saying the jar was corrupt.

How do I install mods for vanilla Minecraft?

Comment: Isn't modded vanilla Minecraft an oxymoron?

Comment: @fredley: Perhaps a better title would be "How can I install mods for a non-Bukkit Minecraft server?"

Comment: @fredley, if you can't figure out that the vanilla server is the one developed by Mojang, then you shouldn't be playing this game.

Comment: Some people don't know the vanilla terminology, and vanilla means no modifications. Okay, so changing the title wasn't _necessary_, but changing it back was pointless.

Comment: You may be aware of this, but you have not accepted an answer. Do this by clicking the check mark beside the answer that you think best answers the question : )

Comment: @AidanMueller I was aware of that but haven't had time to test this. I just did and yes it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you **don't** delete the "META-INF" for the server. this will corrupt it. also make sure you download the server mod. not the client mod

Answer (score 0):

Some mods are written for the normal minecraft server rather than bukkit; you have to be sure that your mod is one of those. It ought to be the same as installing a mod on a normal client at that point.

<strike>The "jar corrupt" issue often happens when you forget to delete the "META-INF" folder for a mod that requires it. This folder contains things that help verify that the jar hasn't been tampered with, and leaving it unchanged can result in the jar registering as having been "corrupted'. More information on meta-inf can be found [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/852702-meta-inf/).</strike>

Apparently multiplayer requires the meta-inf folder. So I would posit that either you're not following the instructions exactly or that the instructions have changed with newer versions of minecraft.

Comment: I understand how META-INF works. I deleted that directory but still get the jar corruption issue.

Comment: Continuing what Yamikurone said, the mod may not support multiplayer.

Comment: @SmilingDevil Good point, though I assumed if there was a youtube walkthrough for installing a specific mod on a server that it was multiplayer-friendly.

Comment: No, he's doing it on the server. on the server you *CAN'T* delete the "META-INF". read the server installation section in the spoiler [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/182918-11-123smp-flans-mods-planes-ww2-guns-vehicles-playerapi-moods-mputils-teams/#MLM)

Answer (score 0):

While this is *technically* not a solution to your problem, I thought I'd point you to [tekkit](http://www.technicpack.net/tekkit/) (based on bukkit) which combines buildcraft, industrialcraft2, redpowered and some other plugins (which can be individually deactivated). Just note that you will also need to use the Technic Launcher instead of the vanilla client, but otherwise you'd have to mod the client by yourself anyway...